# Apply a filter criteria to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe like this

| Material_no | cal_year_month | Historical Demand | Sum_of_historical_demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-07-01 | 90 | 930 |
| 123 | 2022-04-01 | 100 | 930 |
| 123 | 2021-09-01 | 150 | 930 |
| 123 | 2022-04-01 | 50 | 930 |
| 123 | 2022-05-01 | 90 | 930 |
| 123 | 2021-10-01 | 40 | 930 |
| 123 | 2020-04-01 | 90 | 930 |
| 123 | 2020-07-01 | 100 | 930 |
| 123 | 2020-07-01 | 90 | 930 |
| 123 | 2020-02-01 | 130 | 930 |

currently  I have the Sum_of_historical_demand to be the sum of Historical Demand grouped by material_no.

I want to change it to only calculate for cal_year_month less than 01 July 2021, but I want the values to appear in the rest of the rows where cal_year_month is greater than 01 July 2021

Sample output I'm looking for

| Material_no | cal_year_month | Historical Demand | Sum_of_historical_demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-07-01 | 90 | 520 |
| 123 | 2022-04-01 | 100 | 520 |
| 123 | 2021-09-01 | 150 | 520 |
| 123 | 2022-04-01 | 50 | 520 |
| 123 | 2022-05-01 | 90 | 520 |
| 123 | 2021-10-01 | 40 | 520 |
| 123 | 2020-04-01 | 90 | 520 |
| 123 | 2020-07-01 | 100 | 520 |
| 123 | 2020-07-01 | 90 | 520 |
| 123 | 2020-02-01 | 130 | 520 |

Currently I have code like this

```
df["sum_of_Historic_Demand"] = df['Cal_year_month'].gt('2021-06-01').groupby(["Material_no"])["Historical_demand"].transform('sum')
```

but this is giving me output like this

| Material_no | cal_year_month | Historical Demand | Sum_of_historical_demand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-07-01 | 90 | 520 |
| 123 | 2022-04-01 | 100 | 520 |
| 123 | 2021-09-01 | 150 | 520 |
| 123 | 2022-04-01 | 50 | 520 |
| 123 | 2022-05-01 | 90 | 520 |
| 123 | 2021-10-01 | 40 | 520 |
| 123 | 2020-04-01 | 90 |  |
| 123 | 2020-07-01 | 100 |  |
| 123 | 2020-07-01 | 90 |  |
| 123 | 2020-02-01 | 130 |  |

How do I get the same values for the rest of the rows.

Please help

Comment: If you want less than 01 July 2021, why are you using `gt('2021-06-01')`, i.e. greater than 01 Jun 2021?

Comment: If the data is ordered as in the example (so all the blanks to be filled are just after or before the full fields, you can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)